# K clustering from Panda Dataframe instead of Sample Data

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis

I have a csv that I imported as a panda into my juypter notebook.
The Panda has 12 columns, one "Timestamp" and then 11 columns with data for different countries.

What I am trying to do is to visualize them in a cluster. I found the following code to create a basic cluster. But I am struggling already for a while to do exactly the same as below with my data. Anyone know what I have to change to replace the random sample data with my panda data?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pylab import mpl, plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
np.random.seed(1000)

from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=250, centers=4, random_state=500, cluster_std=1.25) 

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do a one-dimensional cluster, you can do something like this:

```
someDF = pd.read_csv("myFile.csv")
print(someDF.columns)
columnsOfInterest = ['Austria', 'Norway', 'Belgium', 'Sweden', 'Spain']
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
for c in columnsOfInterest:
    plt.scatter(someDF[c], someDF[c])
plt.show()
```

If you want to do 2d clustering (which is more typical) you can do something like:

```
someDF = pd.read_csv("myFile.csv")
print(someDF.columns)
columnsOfInterest = ['Austria', 'Norway', 'Belgium', 'Sweden', 'Spain']
secondColumn = 'OtherColumn'
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
for c in columnsOfInterest:
    plt.scatter(someDF[c], someDF[secondColumn])
plt.show()
```